# JBOSS: EJB how to fix java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

inside a bean I try to list all the articles with this method

```
public List<Article> listerLesArticles() {
    javax.persistence.Query req = manager.createQuery("select * from Article");
    return req.getResultList();
}
```

from a client when I call the method

```
public void lister() {
    List<Article> arr = epicerie.listerLesArticles();
    System.out.println(" ");
    Iterator<Article> iterator =  arr.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Article unArticle=iterator.next();
        System.out.println(unArticle.getCode());
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

But I get this `Exception`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at $Proxy2.listerLesArticles(Unknown Source)
    at ecpicerie.EpicerieClient.lister(EpicerieClient.java:80)
    at ecpicerie.EpicerieClient.main(EpicerieClient.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException
    at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.ClassLoaderUtility.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtility.java:103)
    at org.jboss.remoting.loading.RemotingClassLoader.loadClass(RemotingClassLoader.java:86)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:334)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.jboss.remoting.loading.ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.resolveClass(ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.java:176)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1592)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1513)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1749)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1887)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1887)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1887)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1346)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:368)
    at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.receiveObjectVersion2_2(JavaSerializationManager.java:238)
    at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.receiveObject(JavaSerializationManager.java:138)
    at org.jboss.remoting.marshal.serializable.SerializableUnMarshaller.read(SerializableUnMarshaller.java:123)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.versionedRead(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:1215)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:845)
    at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:160)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1708)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:612)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.client.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)
    at $Proxy3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:261)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.session.SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:101)
    at $Proxy2.listerLesArticles(Unknown Source)
    at ecpicerie.EpicerieClient.lister(EpicerieClient.java:80)
    at ecpicerie.EpicerieClient.main(EpicerieClient.java:122)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.client.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)
    at $Proxy3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:261)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.session.SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:101)
    ... 3 more
```

on this line

```
List<Article> arr=epicerie.listerLesArticles();
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have two basic problems:

- Your JPQL query is wrong
- Your client doesn't have all required client libraries

See the other answer for the query, but realize that by fixing the query you solved only half of your problem. The documentation of your server should tell you which libs need to be copied (in case of JBoss, it's basically the entire /client lib).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your HQL query to: "from Article". The root cause of this seems to be that you're getting a HQL syntax exception but cannot serialize it to your client side application since it doesn't have JPA's jars.

EDIT: As in Achille's comment, "Select e from Article e" will work as well.